# Angularjs, Typescript, Uglify Failed to instantiate module myApp .... unknown provider: a

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, typescript

I am receiving this error whilst using typescript with angularjs to inject a custom service.  The resulting typescript transpiled JavaScript has been ran through uglify.  The app works when not deployed using uglify.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyModule due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: a
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$injector/unpr?...<omitted>...2)
```

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mX7TCPAO3VycUp4Nw2Oy?p=preview

I am aware that it works by altering the uglify options to remove mangle, but I would like to keep mangle.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's because the uglifier tries to inject an object named a, without telling the angular injector the name of that object in the $inject register.

Use ngMin before uglify.

Use (edit)  :

```
var config = (function() {
  function modConfig($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'MainController',
        templateUrl: 'sub.html'
    });
  }
  modConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
})();
angular.module('MyModule', ['ngRoute']).config(config);
```

Comment: I am explicitly using $inject to tell angular the service name.  Not sure if ng-min will work in this case

Comment: You forgot to inject $routeProvider in MyModule :)

Comment: Cannot get this to work :-( Any chance you could alter the plunker to correct my attempt ?? :-)

Comment: Ok got it working using this; `angular.module('MyModule', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'MainController',
        templateUrl: 'sub.html'
    });
  }])
  .service('LocationService', My_Module.LocationService)
  .controller('MainController', My_Module.MainController);`

Comment: Sure, that's what you should use ngmin for rather than mixing $inject and the injection array.

Comment: I agree ng-min would have caught this one, but my typescript controllers themselves cannot use ng-min as they're not created in the same way.  Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is minification substitutes input parameter names and function names. So in your case

```
var LocationService = (function () {
        function LocationService($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.foo = 123;
        }
        LocationService.prototype.log = function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        };
        LocationService.$inject = ['$rootScope'];
        return LocationService;
    })();
```

got minified to

```
var b=function(){function a(a){a.foo=123}... 
a.$inject=["LocationService"]
```

So LocationService was renamed to "b" and your code still tried to inject "LocationService", which obviously does not exist.

One option may be to use something like ngMin or ngAnnotate (I haven't tried these), but my personal preference is to use the inline array notation to declare dependencies to obviate this problem.

Comment: a.LocationService = b, LocationSercice still exists though.  When debugging MyModule.LocationService is present.  I'm not sure how I can use ngMin, ngAnnotate as these controllers are generated from typescript classes automatically, this is why I use $inject = ["LocationService"].